# Symfony2 - register vendor as service

Tags: php, symfony, service

I want to register vendor library as service, like doctrine, which anybody can access via `$container->get('doctrine')`. I want to register with that way another vendors, for example PhpExcel (`$container->get('phpexcel')`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [services.yml](https://github.com/liuggio/ExcelBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/services.yml) file from [liuggio/ExcelBundle](https://github.com/liuggio/ExcelBundle)

```
parameters:
    xls.phpexcel.class: PHPExcel

services:
    xls.phpexcel:
        class: %xls.phpexcel.class%
```

And then `$container->get('xls.phpexcel');`

Comment: ...and remember to delete cache directory instead of `cache:clear`

Answer (score 0):

As long as 3rd party classes respect DI by not instantiating their dependencies themselves, you can register them as services just like you would your own classes. Read the [*Service Container* chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) to get more information on how to do that.

Comment: When I create Bundle/Resources/config/services.yml, and add lines:
`phpexcel:
        class: PHPExcel\PHPExcel`, I've got error:
`Class 'PHPExcel\PHPExcel' not found`. Installed via composer, when I create object of that class, everything works.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just `\PHPExcel`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a working bundle for that. Find all bundles available for composer [at packagist.org](https://packagist.org). The [liuggio/ExcelBundle](https://github.com/liuggio/ExcelBundle) should do the job you want. After installation you can use PHPExcel as a service:

```
$excelService = $this->get('xls.service_xls5');
```